# Why should not violate foreign key while enable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Why should not violate foreign key while enable in SQL Server?

We have two tables, `Order Header` and `Order Detail`.

`Order header` table's `OrderID` column references `OrderDetail` table's `OrderID` column.

Then I'm going to migrate with some data from production database to these table.
I just disable these table foreign key constraint and inserted data from production Db.

After insertion of data, the order details table's `OrderID` column contains the values `101,102,103`, but the order header table's `Order ID` column contains value `100` only.

Then I try to enable the foreign key constraint using the following t-sql code

```
exec sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL"
```

Why should not violate the foreign key with existing data while enabling?

Answer (score 3):

When you moving data from multiple tables which connected with FKey - you should:

- or preserve key values in both tables
- or issue new values changing appropriate FKey column in referencing table when moving

When you enabling the FKey constraint - it is by default checks for data consistency